# Any tips on keeping straight lines in drywall on ceiling with multiple angles?

Tags: drywall, attic-conversion

I am getting ready to hang drywall in my attic. The ceiling is 5 feet wide and that transitions to 45 degree sections that are approximately 4 feet wide and that transitions to vertical walls. The picture below is for reference. Does anyone have any tips to keep straight lines in the transitions?  Should I start on the ceiling or start at the floor? My first thought was to make all the ceiling pieces the same width and center them the length of the attic.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always start with the ceiling boards first. Then the vertical wall boards help hold the edges of the ceiling boards up.

Tape and mud.  If you have cut the boards fairly straight, the edge lines will be as straight as needed.  ( may not be perfect, but not noticeable.)

Comment: If you can lay your hands on it, Strait-Flex Perfect 90 Drywall Joint Tape is awesome for straight lines with non-90° corners.